# Why is my code inserting extra spaces into strings?

Tags: python, replace

Here's the code:

```py
import re
def convert_to_lower(match_obj):
    if match_obj.group() is not None:
        return match_obj.group().lower()
while True:
    print("Input text")
    OUTPUT = input()
    if OUTPUT == "CHANGE MODE":
        break
    OUTPUT = re.sub("[A-Z]", convert_to_lower, OUTPUT)
    OUTPUT = OUTPUT.replace("a","")
    OUTPUT = OUTPUT.replace("c","")
    OUTPUT = OUTPUT.replace("e","")
    OUTPUT = OUTPUT.replace("f","")
    OUTPUT = OUTPUT.replace("i","")
    OUTPUT = OUTPUT.replace("o","")
    OUTPUT = OUTPUT.replace("r","")
    OUTPUT = OUTPUT.replace("t","")
    OUTPUT = OUTPUT.replace("u","")
    OUTPUT = OUTPUT.replace("v","")
    OUTPUT = OUTPUT.replace("w","")
    OUTPUT = OUTPUT.replace("x","")
    OUTPUT = OUTPUT.replace("y","")
    print(OUTPUT)
```

When I run the code outside of the IDLE shell, it will insert extra spaces into the outputted string if any characters were replaced. The number of spaces and the location is different for different strings, though it's always the same for strings that are the same in terms of positions of replaced characters (for example, "lalalalala" would be considered the same as "nanananana") and the location is usually 30+ characters into the string. This doesn't happen when the code is run in the IDLE shell, so my best guess is that it has something to do with the program being unable to display the characters (they all get displayed as a question mark in a box), but I really don't know.

I've tried with different replacement, but the problem persists as long as there the replacement includes characters that can't be displayed (with one exception I've found, that being "⭙", but there could be others) which lines up with my theory that it's to do with the characters themselves, but that doesn't help me figure out why it's happening or how to prevent it (other than just "use different characters" or "only run this code in the IDLE shell"). I've also tried using "re.sub" instead of "OUTPUT.replace", but that doesn't fix the issue either.

Edit: A commenter requested a screenshot, so hopefully this helps.
[image: a screenshot of the issue]

Comment: I know screenshots are discouraged on this site, but I think in this instance a few screenshots can help clarify what the error is. The code runs fine on my end.

Comment: @FelixFourcolor I added a screenshot to demonstrate the issue, I hope this is helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be a problem with the interface display, special character text is displayed properly,

But problems with command line or display interface output

I tried some output methods

pycharm

[image]

/bin/bash

[image: Input text lalalala llll Input text]

windows11 cmd

[image]

It looks like it has Spaces, but if you try to copy and paste into the text and you find that it's showing, then maybe there's a problem with the encoding of the characters that are showing,

Is that what you want to be sure of, or is that what happened?

Comment: Copy-pasting the text copies the spaces too, if that's what you were asking.

Comment: According to your picture, why do I see the py.exe program?

You packaged it as an exe, right?

Then execute the exe file?

Comment: I have it saved as a .py file, and I'm just double-clicking to open from File Explorer.